# Why would the presence of a 'lock' statement in a C# method significantly increase its runtime, even if the lock statement is never executed?

Tags: c#, performance, locking

For ten million iterations, I was comparing different ways of accessing a singleton.

Direct read of a static property is fastest.

`Lazy<T>`, whose `Value` property internally introduces s a null check, cast of boxed value, and access of boxed value takes a little longer (2x - 3x).

What I found startling is that a common double-check lock pattern, which is really just a null check for most accesses, was taking significantly longer (almost 5x in some cases) -- far longer than expected. I was also shocked to discover that simply commenting out the 'lock' statement, even if it was never hit, reduces the time closer to a basic direct access of static property, with a little extra overhead for the null check.

What is it about the mere presence of this 'lock' statement in the method, even if the lock statement is never executed, that's causing it to take so much more time? I assign the singleton(s) up-front in this test code, so the lock statement is never hit; yet, simply uncommenting the 'lock' line increases the runtime. I have no explanation.

Here's a short example you can paste in a console app and run to see the timings of a few different accesses.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace SingletonInitializationMethodPerformanceTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        private const int TestRuns = 5;
        private const int AccessesPerTestRun = 10000000;
        private static int _totalAccesses;
        private static readonly Stopwatch Timer = new Stopwatch();
        private static readonly Func<Singleton>[] Tests = { Singleton.LazyInstance, Singleton.InstanceWithLockPresent, Singleton.InstanceWithLockCommentedOut, Singleton.InstanceWithLockInSeparateMethod, Singleton.DirectlyReturnedInstance };

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var results = Tests.Select(x => new int[TestRuns]).ToList();
            Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest; Thread.Sleep(3000);
            for (var iRun = 0; iRun < TestRuns; iRun++)
                for (var iTest = 0; iTest < Tests.Length; iTest++)
                    results[iTest][iRun] = RunTest(Tests[iTest]);

            Console.Write($"Total accesses: {_totalAccesses}\n\n");
            for (var iTest = 0; iTest < Tests.Length; iTest++)
                Console.Write($"{Tests[iTest].Method.Name.PadRight(35, ' ')} [{string.Join(",", results[iTest].Select(x => x.ToString().PadLeft(5, ' ')))}]\n");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static int RunTest(Func<Singleton> getSingleton)
        {
            Timer.Restart();
            for (var i = 0; i < AccessesPerTestRun; i++)
                _totalAccesses += getSingleton().Value;
            Timer.Stop();
            return (int)Timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
        }
    }

    public class Singleton
    {
        private static readonly object _initializationLock = new object();
        private static Singleton _instance = new Singleton(); //Instance is pre-assigned for testing purposes, ensuring 'lock' statement is never hit; demonstrating the statement's presence alone increases runtime.
        private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> _lazyInstance = new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton(), LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);

        public static Singleton LazyInstance() => _lazyInstance.Value;
        
        public static Singleton InstanceWithLockPresent()
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                lock (_initializationLock) //intentionally unreachable code; represents code that would be here if we were not pre-assigning the singleton for testing
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                    {
                        _instance = new Singleton();
                    }
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }

        public static Singleton InstanceWithLockCommentedOut()
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                //lock (_initializationLock) //intentionally unreachable code; represents code that would be here if we were not pre-assigning the singleton for testing
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                    {
                        _instance = new Singleton();
                    }
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }

        public static Singleton InstanceWithLockInSeparateMethod() => _instance ?? DoLock();
       
        private static Singleton DoLock()
        {
            lock (_initializationLock)
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }

        public static Singleton DirectlyReturnedInstance() => _instance;

        public int Value => 1;

        private Singleton()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Here are some example runtimes (total milliseconds per 10 million iterations, repeated five times for each method of accessing the singleton).

[image]

Comment: By commenting out the lock statement and the block below it, you render the `if` statement meaningless-- it doesn't matter whether `_doubleCheckInstance` is null. My guess is that the `if` statement itself is being optimized out of the equation too. Removal of the `if` means that you have a much cleaner pipeline since branch prediction is not needed.

Comment: No, that's not it. If I move the lock statement into a separate method, and put a call to that method where the lock statement is... it still runs fast.  Besides, there's still a 'throw' there; it's not like I'm commenting out all of the code in the if block; just the lock statement. It's as though calling a method that simply has a lock statement in it is slower for some reason.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that we can performance measure?

Comment: As a side note, posting code as an image is frowned upon here. Also personally I find the overlaid hand-drawn text especially ugly, hence my downvote. Otherwise your question is quite interesting.

Comment: I fixed the post to avoid the code image. It was only intended to illustrate what I meant by commenting out a lock statement, not really present code. I added minimal code to demonstrate timing of these access methods. It shows that direct access of static variable is fastest, commenting out the lock or moving the lock to a separate method are next fastest, next is a lazy instance, and finally the typical double-check lock all in one method is slowest.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely because a lock introduces a try/finally, a local, and quite a bit of code - plus memory barrier semantics, making the JIT not want to inline your method any more?

A common hack here is to have the success path in the main method, and the "double checked" failure path in a different method, so all that overhead only gets executed in the null case. For example:

```cs
return _doubleCheckInstance ?? SlowPath();
```

with a separate `SlowPath` method that does all the hard work including the lock and new

Comment: I think that might explain what's going on. I tried moving the lock into a separate method, and it remained fast.